# Angle offset in the Line Direction Histogram Plugin

Tags: qgis

Can someone please explain what the angle offset is in the QGIS Line Direction Histogram Plugin. I have tried using a search engine to figure it out but I cant. I am using the plugin to calculate orientation of different vector lines.

Answer (score 1):

The offset angle is where the **first sector** begins from due North.  This is described in their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/havatv/qgislinedirectionhistogramplugin/blob/9341b01f573010e7218f802218b87e1c632886be/linedirectionhistogram_dialog.py#L314):

> The first sector starts at (or close to) north (the y-axis), and extends clockwise. If the user has specified an offset, the sector starts either east                (negative offset) or west (positive offset) of north.

They also have [documentation for their plugin](http://arken.nmbu.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/LineDirectionHistogram/).

Answer (score 0):

The offset is also explained in the plugin Help:

`Angle offset specifies an offset (clockwise from north) for the direction bins (the default is 0).`